# MAX11645EUA+T ADC Readings

Tags: adc, esp32, thermistor

I am having issues with ADC readings with MAX11645EUA+T. I have a 2 input ADC and am driving the inputs with thermistors buffered each with a voltage follower. The ADC works when I have both thermistors attached but the problem I am facing is when I unplug one of them, the other reads 1-2 degrees higher. I am confused because its not like the input to the ADC is floating; it is essentially driven to the rail - 1.2V. I was wondering if anyone else has run into issues like this before. I have attached images to show what the circuit looks like.

[image: ADC with Inputs]

[image: Thermistor Inputs]

Comment: Is there any noise on the cable , long wires , or unusual grounding or spare input crosstalk when tested with a pot or fixed R’s.

Answer (score 1):

When multiplexed inputs of an ADC are influencing each other often times the issue is the sample and hold circuit inside the ADC not having enough time to settle on the new voltage after switching inputs.

Essentially you can try two things: Stretch the time the ADC is sampling the input (usually via the serial interface) or increase the drive capability of your buffer circuit (usually by reducing the series resistor and/or increasing the buffer capacitor to provide more instantaneous charge when the ADC is switching inputs).

Comment: Understood. The issue is that the ADC value never goes back to what it should be unless the other thermistor is connected. I have also tried to increase the drive with making the 220 ohm to a 0 ohm and the readings become worse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the opamp is supplied from the 3v3 rail, but with no thermistor has 5v on one input. This is not good, but will probably peg output to 3v3.

The ADC has 2.5V vref, so the 3v3 input for the unplugged channel will substantially exceed the mapped range.  This kind of overrange input can easily upset the accuracy when switching channels.

Comment: The output of the op amp is a darling pair. Max output I can get on it is Rail voltage -1.2v ish so about 2.1V. I understand it’s not the best practice but it shouldn’t effect the ADC

Comment: Understood.  

Have you verified the actual opamp output voltage when there is no thermistor, and the + input is at 5V? 

Also worth checking how much your 5V ref changes when one thermistor is removed.  I know you're using the divided value as VREF, but for each 1mV of shift in the 5V, the ref for the ADC is only changing by 0.5mV...

Comment: After doing some digging this morning, "5V" read 5.008V and at the + input reads 4.984V. No matter what is connected (one therm, both, or none) the 5V reference reads either 5.007 or 5.008 V. I have the voltages spitting out in terminal and when I unplug one, the one plugged in reads ~20mV lower.